# Update the css of one loaded DOM asynchronously once another user clicks a button in his loaded DOM in a django webapp

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am developing a django webapp where I have one html that gets loaded for two different users (User1 and User2) with some slight changes in it. I want my user1 to disable/enable some of the fields (like  field) of that html in runtime so that user2 can only update the ones that user1 has made enabled.

Currently, user1 can disable/enable html elements via javascript but that changes are only being reflected in his html. User2 cannot see the changes in his html.

What will be the perfect way to achieve this functionality? I am not very familiar with everything in Django. Pardon my obvious knowledge gaps.

Thanks.

Comment: When user1 changes something, you want user2 to see this change affected in his browser in real time? To do this, you will have to make frequent calls to the server from user2.

Comment: I think I understand what you are pointing at. Can you give me a bit more detail on how to implement such frequent calls to django server?

Comment: Your best bet is to use either WebSockets, or WebRTC. I recommend looking at a tutorial on WebSockets.

Comment: In a JavaScript loop (like using `setTimeout` or something similar) you can make ajax calls to the Django server. If you had a bit more code to work with, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made it work using "Websockets (javascript)" and "django-channels". 
In my html, I created a websocket connection and sent the information of the fields that user1 wanted to disable to my django server. 
Once that message is received by django server it sends the exact information back to my html which is being received by "websockets.onmessage" function.
I update the fields accordingly inside the "websockets.onmessage" function.